# Hit a URL using groovy step

Tags: groovy, soapui

I created a HTTP request step and checked the response code 200/400 . 
The same i want to check using groovy only. No HTTP requeststep. Use only groovy step.

URL response script:-

```
def rawResponse = new String(testRunner.testCase.testSteps["HTTP Request"].testRequest.response.rawResponseData)
log.info rawResponse
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils( context )
def httpResponseHeaders = context.testCase.testSteps["HTTP Request"].testRequest.response.responseHeaders
def httpStatus = httpResponseHeaders["#status#"]
def httpStatusCode = (httpStatus =~ "[1-5]\\d\\d")[0]

log.info("HTTP status code: " + httpStatusCode)

if (httpStatusCode == "200")
{
log.info "Success"
}
   else
   {
   log.info "Failure"
   }
```

Comment: Maybe some code would be helpfull for us to give you some answers.

Comment: Here i am reading response of HTTP Request step. i want to hit endpoint url in groovy only. Don't wanna use HTTP req step.

Comment: @sunny, if not yet, propbably [this](https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder/wiki/GET-Examples) might be what you are after? By the way, what is benefit that you get using `SoapUI`?

Comment: You can use https://github.com/jgritman/httpbuilder But like @Rao said: what is the point if you have SoapUI?